# Spring MVC Checkboxes Path

Tags: spring-mvc, checkbox

I have the following on the JSP

`<form:form method="post" action="${submit}" id="id" commandName="object">
 <form:checkboxes path="ratings" items="${ratingsList}">`

Here, the ratingsList is set in the Controller.

`model.put("object",object);
model.put("ratingsList",ratingsList);`

I see all the checkboxes on the page when it is loaded. I am able to save it too in the ratings which is a list. But, when I come back to this page, I want that the ratings that are saved in the "ratings" - list are selected on the page.

I am getting the below error.

`Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Unable to convert value "[0]" from type 'java.util.List' to type 'java.lang.String'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:`

Comment: Could you write the output of simply dumping object.ratings list elements with c:forEach? And is this a list of strings or some other type?

Comment: This is a list of long. I have the object saved in the database. So, when I load it the first time, they are checked ! But, when I change them and later come back to the page, I get this error